# Old-style Kenmore washer door switch

Tags: doors, washer

Is there an adjustment I can make to the door switch plate? It's the top loader, old style door lid switch with the little pin in the lid that makes contact with the switch plate when the lid's closed, letting the washer know it's ok to do it's thing....
Recently, it'll stop washing mid-cycle. I'm assuming the agitation does something that causes the switch and pin to slightly separate(like on a heavy wash cycle and the clothes are really sloshing around in there).
It's definitely the switchplate/pin that's the problem...I took off the rubber protector ring around the pin, and it works fine. It's almost like this bumper-ring is too thick and causing the pin/plate to not make full contact. But it's the original bumper. I haven't swapped any parts or done anything.
I can wash clothes just fine now with the bumper ring removed, but I'm worried someone will close the lid too firmly and snap the pin it was on.
I'm wondering if the pin is replaceable or the switchplate can be adjusted up/down? I can't see spending $50 plus time to install a new switchplate if this one isn't broken...something just needs adjusting.

Comment: There's normally no adjustment in mechanisms like that. They're just designed to have enough free play that none is needed. Post photos for a more confident answer (or at least a model number).

Comment: It is possible the plastic piece is worn adding a small price of rubber to the plate may be all you need.

Comment: Kenmore model 110.25852400

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to DIY!

I actually had this exact problem with my Kenmore washer last week. The plastic clip built into the switch had worn out. After unsuccessfully trying to fix it several time, each time making the problem worse, I just bypassed the switch with a jumper. The washer will run with the top up or down but doesn't splash enough to cause a mess.

Before doing something like this, consider your environment, such as if you have young children who may get hurt trying to use the washer for a jacuzzi. As long as nobody will be doing anything stupid, there is no need to pay the premium for a new switch (if you can find it) or a new washer.

Comment: What gauge wire did you use for the jumper?

Comment: @paul I think it was a #16. I just cut a short piece from a scrap solid core romex that was thicker than the leads going to the switch. I did have to file the conductor down a hair to get it to fit in the connector.